# Import custom text format without separators

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, ssis, etl

I would like import this .txt file format to SQL Server Table or to convert each block of text to pipe separated line.

Which tools or C# solution suggests you to resolve this issue?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You.

```
=================
INPUT (.txt file)
=================
ID: 37
Name: Josephy Murphy
Email: jmurphy@email.com
Description: bla, bla, bla, bla...

ID: 38
Name: Paul Newman
Email: pnewman@email.com
Description: bla, bla, bla, bla...

:
:

=========================
OUTPUT (SQL Server Table)
=========================

ID | Name           | Email             | Description  
37 | Josephy Murphy | jmurphy@email.com | bla, bla, bla, bla...
38 | Paul Newman    | pnewman@email.com | bla, bla, bla, bla...

:
:
```

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck while trying this yourself? Note that (1) "which tools do you suggest" is off-topic on SO, (2) "what is the best way to do X",  where a million answers are possible is also off-topic, as it will attract opinionated answers as well as being to broad. I am voting to close this question. Please read [how do i ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a DataTable I'm now writing directly to SQL Server.  You need to enter a connection string and the name of the SQL Table in the Insert SQL.

If you are really adding that many lines I would consider using SQLCMD.EXE which comes with SQL Server.  it accepts any separator for the data and a string SQL.  I never used it with an Insert, I usually use it for Select SQL.  There is a host of different command line executable that work with SQL Server.  See webpage below
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        enum States
        {
            FIND_OUTPUT,
            GET_SEPERATOR,
            GET_TABLE_HEADER,
            GET_DATA_TABLE,
            END
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            States state = States.FIND_OUTPUT;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";

            string connStr = "Enter your connection string here";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            string[] headers = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case States.FIND_OUTPUT:
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("OUTPUT (SQL Server Table)"))
                                state = States.GET_SEPERATOR;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_SEPERATOR:
                            state = States.GET_TABLE_HEADER;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_TABLE_HEADER:
                            headers = inputLine.Split(new char[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            headers = headers.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
                            state = States.GET_DATA_TABLE;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_DATA_TABLE:
                            string[] dataArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            dataArray = dataArray.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
                            string commandText = string.Format("Insert into table1 ({0}) values ({1})", string.Join(",", headers), "'" + string.Join("','", dataArray) + "'");
                            cmd.CommandText = commandText;    
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state == States.GET_DATA_TABLE)
                        break; //exit while loop if blank row at end of data table
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Hello! I need to use the solution with SSIS. That is, turn these 4 lines in just one line and delete the labels: ID:, Name:, Email:,Description:. Using Script Component SSIS believe to be a practical solution. What do you think? The problem is to transform (Text File): (4 lines -> 1 line without labels) Example-> ID: 37 Name: Josephy Murphy Email: jmurphy@email.com Description: bla, bla, bla, bla... =>(CSV Result): 37;Josephy Murphy;jmurphy@email.com;bla, bla, bla, bla... What do you think?

Comment: The code produces one line.

Comment: I have a SQL Select query where I'm using SQLCMD.EXE to get around 1 million rows of data.  It takes about 1/2 hour for the query to run.  I'm using SQLCMD.EXE because VS code take a lot longer.  I would recommend the following in the order shown. 1) Use bulk copy if the old database exists.  You can run bulk copy either from BCP.EXE or from VS.  2) Use VS to save file in format that BCP.EXE or SQLCMD.EXE can read.  You can use any separator including '|'.  Or use my original code with datatable and save results to XML using WriteXML() method.  3) Use my lastest code as is.

Comment: There is no difference in using SSIS, SQLCMD.EXE, or BCP.EXE.  The two .EXE are nice because you can setup a BAT file to automatically run the SQL rather than opening up a GUI and manually having to run the SQL.  The best way of doing you task is to run a C# application to create a text file that SSIS, SQLCMD.EXE, or BCP can read.  Then input  the text file with any of the three methods.

Answer (score 0):

Real simple to parse this file.  Been doing projects like this for 40 years.  See code below.  I put results into a DataTable.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        enum States
        {
            FIND_OUTPUT,
            GET_SEPERATOR,
            GET_TABLE_HEADER,
            GET_DATA_TABLE,
            END
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

            States state = States.FIND_OUTPUT;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case States.FIND_OUTPUT:
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("OUTPUT (SQL Server Table)"))
                                state = States.GET_SEPERATOR;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_SEPERATOR:
                            state = States.GET_TABLE_HEADER;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_TABLE_HEADER:
                            state = States.GET_DATA_TABLE;
                            break;
                        case States.GET_DATA_TABLE:
                            string[] dataArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                            dt.Rows.Add(dataArray);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state == States.GET_DATA_TABLE)
                        break; //exit while loop if blank row at end of data table
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Congratulations! Reading the code i understand the logic of the program structure. Do you know any tool that does this import to SQL Sever? (Performance - 15,000,000 lines to read)...

Answer (score 0):

Easy in Python:

```
input='''\
ID: 37
Name: Josephy Murphy
Email: jmurphy@email.com
Description: bla, bla, bla, bla...

ID: 38
Name: Paul Newman
Email: pnewman@email.com
Description: bla, bla, bla, bla...'''

import re
fields=('ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'Description')
out={k:[] for k in fields}
for m in re.finditer(r'(^ID.*?(?=^ID|\Z))', input, flags=re.S | re.M):
    for k, v in [map(str.strip, line.split(':')) for line in m.group(1).splitlines() if line.strip()]:
        out[k].append(v)

# you now have all the data in a structure that could be used with SQL
# just print to show...    
fmt='{:3}| {:20}| {:20}| {:20}'
print fmt.format(*fields)    
for i in range(len(out['ID'])):
    print fmt.format(*[out[k][i] for k in fields])
```

Prints:

```
ID | Name                | Email               | Description         
37 | Josephy Murphy      | jmurphy@email.com   | bla, bla, bla, bla...
38 | Paul Newman         | pnewman@email.com   | bla, bla, bla, bla...
```

Comment: Congratulations! Unfortunately, I do not know Python. Do you know any tool that does this import to SQL Sever? (Performance - 15,000,000 lines to read)...